# Firebase does not stop sending messages

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, express, firebase-cloud-messaging

From my front (angular 4) I make a call to node, this server node using the firebase API. The function messaging (). sendToDevice (param1, param2).

The problem is that after I send a notification, it does not stop sending notifications every minute or 4 minutes, when I run it from the firebase console.

MY front is developed with angular 4,
back node.js, 
API firebase (firebase-admin),
method messaging().sendToDevice(token,message)

Angular 4:

```
public sendMessage(token){
    var message = {
         notification: {
            title: 'NOTIFICACIÓN',  
            body: 'Notificación enviada desde el panel de administración'
         },
         data: {
            contentUrl: 'https://as.com',
            contentType: 'firma'
         }
         //token: token
    };
    this.firebase.sendMessage(this.url, message).subscribe((result) => {});
}
```

Node.js

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(req.body.token,req.body)
  .then(function(response){
      console.log("ha ido perfecto el envio del message---->>",response);
      res.json(message) 
  })
  .catch(function(err){ 
      console.log("Ha ocurrido un error------------->", err) 
  });
```

**CallBacks**
-first message callback:

```
{
  results: [
   { 
    messageId: '0:1560440395028889%83725e9583725e95'
   }
 ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 0,
  successCount: 1,
  multicastId: 5776433739052639000 
}
```

-rest of messages:

```
  ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

solved!

**Angular 4 component:**

```
    public sendMessage(token){
    var message = {
         notification: {
            title: 'NOTIFICACIÓN',  
            body: 'Notificación enviada desde el panel de administración'
         },
         data: {
            contentUrl: 'https://as.com',
            contentType: 'firma'
         }
         //token: token
    };
    this.firebase.sendMessage(this.url, message).subscribe((result) => {});
   }
```

**Angular 4 service:**

```
// sendMessage
sendMessage(url: string, message:any) {
  this.http.post('https://' + url + this.URL_API +'/sendmessage', message).subscribe((res)=>{console.log("res",res);      ;
});
}
```

**NodeJS controller:**

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(req.body.token,req.body)
  .then(function(response){
      console.log("ha ido perfecto el envio del message---->>",response);
  })
  .catch(function(err){ 
      console.log("Ha ocurrido un error------------->", err) 
  });
```

I have removed the subscribe from the component,
in the service I have removed the return and added a subscribe.
the nodejs driver I left it the same